# How to allow shown bootstrap tab to be clicked again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The default behavior on bootstrap tabs is to not allow click on the shown tab.
How can I "disable" this and allow the user to click again the shown tab?
Because I am using AJAX to load a page, it will reload it.

This is a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xfw8t/12/

```
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
          <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
          <li><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
          <li><a data-target="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Message</div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings</div>
        </div>

jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#myTab a:last').tab('show')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you mean

```
$('#myTab').on('click',function(e){
    console.log($(e.target).text())
        //your ajax code goes here to load what your need....

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/1482/

Comment: tabs are not changing though

Comment: you have to do somethign for it to change.  the code above just detects the repeat clicks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to let the user click the selected tab in order to update the contents of that tab.

Solution 1: Employ an onclick event.

```
<a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab" onclick="window.location.reload();"> Home</a>
```

Solution 2: Activate a tab using jQuery

```
$( "#tabId" ).tabs({ active: # });
```

Replace the `#` with the indended tab index (which will be a number).

Answer (score 0):

I tried with JQuery removeClass , because the tab activation is getting applied by class - "active"

So i am just removing it and making it available for click .

HTML:

```
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
            <li><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
            <li class="aa"><a class="clickme" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#settings" >Settings</a></li>
          </ul>

          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Message</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings</div>
          </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    $('#myTab').on('click',function(){

    setTimeout(aa, 20);

    })

    function aa(){
    //alert("hi");
    $(".aa").removeClass('active');

     //$("li:last").off(".active");
     console.log(e.target);

    }
```

Jsfiddle URL for reference - 
http://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/xFW8t/1485/

Hope this is helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Got your solution. Main goal is to remove the active `class` of active tab's `li` and your custom `class`. In here i have added `custom-active` in place of `active`.

```
$(function () {
    var ok = $('#myTab a:last').tab('show')
    $(document).on('click', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function () {
      if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')){
          var $link = $('li.active a[data-toggle="tab"]');
          $link.parent().removeClass('active');
          var tabLink = $link.attr('href');
          $('#myTab a[href="' + tabLink + '"]').tab('show');
          $link.parent().addClass('custom-active');
       }
  });
})
```

For this you need bit of style like..

```
#myTab {

    .custom-active {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }

}
```